# Android : setAlarmManager(...) open an activity instead of delaying the opening

Tags: android, android-activity, alarmmanager, synchronize

In android, I have to set an alarm at a special hour that will ring and open an activity at the correct time of the day.

My problem is that the function "alarmManager.set(...)" **OPEN INSTANTLY** the targeted activity and, when the time is reached, open again the same activity.

I don't understand why this happening how can I correct it ?

Current State : I have a timepicker which help me to select the time. I also have a button which call the function alarmManager.set() when I click on it by retrieving the time from the timepicker and calculate the next alarm in ms.

Thx

Code of the button :

```
public void setTheAlarm(View view) {

    TimePicker tp_clock = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tp_timeToRing);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int alarmHours = tp_clock.getCurrentHour();
    int alarmMinutes = tp_clock.getCurrentMinute();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set for " + alarmHours + "h" + alarmMinutes, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Long time = calculateTime(alarmHours, alarmMinutes);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
}
```

Code of the function calculateTime :

```
public Long calculateTime(int alarmHours, int alarmMinutes) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentHours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    if (c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 1)
        currentHours +=12;
    int currentMinutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int setAlarmHours = 0;
    int setAlarmMinutes = 0;
    int balanceWithMinute = 0;

    if (alarmMinutes >= currentMinutes) {

        setAlarmMinutes = alarmMinutes - currentMinutes;
    }
    else {

        setAlarmMinutes = (60 - currentMinutes) + alarmMinutes;
        balanceWithMinute = 1;
    }
    if (alarmHours > currentHours)
        setAlarmHours = alarmHours - currentHours;

    if (alarmHours < currentHours)
        setAlarmHours = (24 - currentHours) +alarmHours - balanceWithMinute;

    if (alarmHours == currentHours && balanceWithMinute == 1)
        setAlarmHours = 23;

    Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+setAlarmHours*setAlarmMinutes*60*1000;
    return time;
}
```

Code of the alarmManager :

```
package fr.pixelcraft.victor.wackertest.SoundPackage;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import fr.pixelcraft.victor.wackertest.LoginActivity;

public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String userToken;
    private String userId;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent i=new Intent(context, PlanASoundActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        userToken = intent.getStringExtra(LoginActivity.USER_TOKEN);
        userId = intent.getStringExtra(LoginActivity.USER_ID);

        i.putExtra(LoginActivity.USER_TOKEN, userToken);
        i.putExtra(LoginActivity.USER_ID, userId);
        context.startActivity(i);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you set a time which is already **past**. This makes the AlarmManager **fire immediately**.

Comment: You're right !
I have to rework my function calculateTime. Thank you !
Post a solution, I'll validate it.

Answer (score 0):

By https://stackoverflow.com/users/2649012/frank-n-stein:

Probably you set a time which is already past. This makes the AlarmManager fire immediately. –